# Filter object by array of property names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have an object like so

```
var obj = { name1: somevalue1, name2: somevalue2, name3: somevalue3}
```

and an array

```
var arr = [name2, name3]
```

Both are dynamically created.
I need to filter object by array(exactly by property names, not by its values).
But so far all methods I've found are about filter by values. 
So result should be

```
var result = {name2: somevalue2, name3: somevalue3}
```

I'm using angular, underscore. I need to filter it not in template, but in controller.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you mean `var arr = ["name2", "name3"]` ?

Comment: Yes, it's var arr = ["name2", "name3"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [_.pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) to "filter" the object.

```js
var obj = { name1: "somevalue1", name2: "somevalue2", name3: "somevalue3"};
var keys = ["name1", "name2"];

console.log(_.pick(obj, keys));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the keys and build a new object with key value pairs.

```js
var obj = { name1: 'somevalue1', name2: 'somevalue2', name3: 'somevalue3' };
    arr = ['name2', 'name3'],
    result = Object.create(null);

arr.forEach(function (k) {
    result[k] = obj[k];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Array#reduce` could be used!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to return object.

```js
var obj = {
  name1: 'somevalue1',
  name2: 'somevalue2',
  name3: 'somevalue3'
}
var arr = ['name2', 'name3']

var result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (arr.indexOf(e) != -1) r[e] = obj[e];
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate for each element of array and check if elements are available in object as key name then put it in result.

```
var obj = { name1: somevalue1, name2: somevalue2, name3: somevalue3};// This is ur object

var arr = [name2, name3];// and this is the array for each element you have to get values from obj

var filterResult = {};// An object to stored the filtered values

arr.forEach(function(elem){ // Iterate for each element of array
    if (obj[elem]) // check in your data object if any key is available of the name of array element 
        filterResult[elem] = obj[elem]; // then put it in filtered object
});

console.log(filterResult);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.